# Proof that $ Y = W^{0} \iff W = \bigcap_{f \in Y} \ker f. $

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a $K-$ vector space with finite dimension. Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$ and $Y$ be a subspace of $V^\ast$. Show that 
$$ Y = W^{0} \iff W = \bigcap_{f \in Y} \ker f. $$

$W^0$ denotes the annihilator of $W$.

My attempt:

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose that $W = \bigcap_{f \in Y} \ker f$. Let $g \in Y$, for each $x \in W$, $x \in \ker f, \, \forall f \in Y$, in particular, $x \in \ker g$, hence $g \in W^0$. Now, let  $g \in W^0$, then $\ker g \subset W = \bigcap_{f \in Y} \ker f$. Then, for $f_0 \in Y, \, \ker g \subset \ker f_0 \Rightarrow g = \alpha f \in Y$. Therefore, $Y = W^0$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Assume that $Y=W^0$. If $x \in W$, $f(x) = 0, \, \forall x \in W^0$, i.e $x \in \bigcap_{f\in W^0} \ker f$. Now, take $x \in \bigcap_{f \in W^0} \ker f$.

I'm stuck in this part to proof that $x\in W$.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $x \in V$ and suppose $f(x) = 0$ for all $f \in W^{0}$. Since $V$ is finite dimensional the subspace $W$ has a basis $w_1, \ldots{}, w_n$. Note that for any $v \in \left<w_1, \ldots, w_n, x\right>$ we have $f(v) = 0$ for any $f \in W^{0}$ (prove this part using the fact that we have a basis). Hence $W^{0} \subset \left<w_1, \ldots, w_n, x\right>^{0}$ and we know the reverse holds since $W \subset \left<w_1, \ldots, w_n, x\right>$ so we find $W = \left<w_1, \ldots, w_n, x\right>$. Hence $x \in W$.